# pass values through to piped dplyr verb inside if{} statement in function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Say I have this data:

```
d <- msleep %>% 
      mutate(comfort_color_desk = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=nrow(msleep)),
             comfort_color_chair = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=nrow(msleep)))
```

I want to pass it through to a `dplyr` chain that lives inside a function i've made, which also includes an indicator to trigger an `{if}` clause inside of the chain.

For example (this works just fine):

```
test_fcn <- function(.x, .y, .count = NULL) {
  .x %>% select(order, .y) %>%
    {if(isTRUE(.count)) count(.,!!ensym(.y)) else .} 
}

d %>% test_fcn(., .y = "comfort_color_desk", .count = TRUE)
```

This shows the basic principle of what I want to do. The problem i'm facing is when I want to just pass through a part of column name and `paste` that with a string and evaluate it as a data column inside the function.

For example (this does not work):

```
test_2_fcn <- function(.x, .y, .z, .compare = NULL) {
  .x %>% 
    {if(isTRUE(.compare)) filter(., paste0("comfort_color_", !!ensym(.y)) == 1 & paste0("comfort_color", !!ensym(.z)) == 1) else .} 
}

d %>% test_2_fcn(., .y = "desk", .z = "chair", .compare = TRUE)
```

I suspect this is a problem with tidy evaluation. Can anyone point in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of tidy evaluation. `paste0` function is being evaluated before the `!!ensym()` is evaluated, now it is tried to paste the literal string `"comfort_color_"` with the symbol `.y` or `.z` instead of the values.

We could use the `sym()` function to convert the string to a symbol and then use `paste()` to concatenate the strings together.

```
library(dplyr)

test_2_fcn <- function(.x, .y, .z, .compare = NULL) {
  .x %>% 
    {if(isTRUE(.compare)) filter(., !!sym(paste0("comfort_color_", .y)) == 1 & !!sym(paste0("comfort_color_", .z)) == 1) else .} 
}

d %>% test_2_fcn(., .y = "desk", .z = "chair", .compare = TRUE)
```

Comment: I was so close... Thanks TarJae!

Comment: I recommend using `.data[[string]]` instead of `!!sym(string)`. We no longer recommend using `!!` for common use cases.

Comment: So I would literally write `{if(isTRUE(.compare)) filter(., !!sym(paste0("comfort_color_", .data[[.y]])) == 1 & !!sym(paste0("comfort_color_", data[[.z]])) == 1) else .}`? Can I ask why`!!` is no longer recommended?  (i'm only just learning it now!)